# Python using django framework - You do not have permission to perform this action ERROR

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-views

I have my feature on my web app where in an admin account can set verification to a company which is the code of that is below. Now when performing the action i cant seem to figure out what is the reason why it is giving my an error "You do not have permission to perform this action ERROR." - 403 Forbidden . In case you wanted to know the FE i have provided also. Thank you. Hope that helps.

## html

```
<button ng-click="main.verifyCompany(company,true)" ng-show="company.is_verified" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> Approve
                            </button>
```

## FE (angular)

```
me.verifyCompany = function (company, verify) {

        if (verify) {
            var message = "Do you really want to activate job posting and other features  for this business account?. Doing so will send an email notification."
        } else {
            var message = "Deactivate posting for this account?."
        }

        confirmSweet.ask(message).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                var filter = {}
                filter.id = company.id
                filter.verify = verify
                AdminService.verify_company(me, filter).then(function (response) {
                    if (response.status == "200") {
                        console.log("Response", response.status)
                        me.get_companies()
                    }
                })
            }
        });

    }
```

## PYTHON CODE

```
class VerifyCompany(APIView):

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,IsCompany,IsAdmin,)

    def get(self, request,company_id):

        data = request.data
        verify = request.GET["verify"]
        verify = True if verify == "true" else False
        company_ins = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)
        company_ins.is_verified = verify
        company_ins.save()

        data = {}
        data["email"] = company_ins.user.email
        print("Ang response data")
        if verify:
            email_ins = Email()
            c_task.delay(email_ins.verification_business_success, data)


        return Response("Company status has been updated.", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: you have set of permissions : IsAuthenticated, IsCompany, IsAdmin. Please Check if the request user is authenticated, company and admin.

Comment: from v1.permissions.myapp_permissions import IsCompany, IsApplicant, IsAdmin , it is bro.

Comment: i mean check if the user you are trying to do certain actions is actually company, admin, etc. I am not talking about imports.

Comment: Ahh I see , so sorry

Comment: It is admin bro

Comment: check if token is valid

Comment: Done bro , thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally When the permissions checks fail either a "403 Forbidden" or "401 Unauthorized"  is returned.
Then in this case you should check

- Request Was not sucessful,403 will be. return. In this case  check `Token` of the User
- Request was successful, but permission was denied.403 will be returned
  In this case you should check if user has given list of `permissions` you have mentioned in the permission classes

more about [permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#how-permissions-are-determined)

Example,
Lets say if user is **John**
and you have set permissions in View as below

`permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,IsCompany,IsAdmin,)`

*then john must be user type company and admin*